# TeeChart: Rounding digits exception for very large data

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, teechart

When I tried to draw a chart with the 
`series.Add(seriesIndex++, data, xTick, System.Drawing.Color.Teal)` 
function which data is lager than 16 digits(for example 6.5E+17), teechart throw the exception as "rounding digits must be between 0 and 15 inclusive. parameter name digits". Is there any way to deal with it? Thanks

Comment: It works fine for me using latest TeeChart.WPF.dll version and the follwoing code snippet. Could you please let us know which TeeChart version are you using, series style you use and a simple code snippet we can run "as-is" to reproduce the problem here? Thanks.
      tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Line()).FillSampleValues();
      tChart1[0].Add(6.5E+17);

Comment: Thank you for you response, the teechart I used is 2009 and the issue occurs when I try to add all same data which only contains eight 6.5E+17 to the series for draw the chart. I trace the code and it is  said in teechart draw axis this SignificantDifference() throw the exception. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I think this bug was fixed some time ago. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug (#TF02016397) which was fixed in Build 4.1.2012.0131x, published on January 2013 as you can see in [TeeChart for .NET version info page](https://www.steema.com/version_info/net/last). Tthis code:

```
  tChart1.Series.Add(new Steema.TeeChart.WPF.Styles.Line());

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    tChart1[0].Add(6.5E+17);        
  }
```

Works fine with current TeeChart.WPF.dll build. Does it crash at your end? You can check latest TeeChart for .NET trial version at https://www.steema.com/product/net